# Iterate over excel worksheet and copy non empty cells value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to iterate over many sheets (33 omg), on every sheet to iterate over column A with range A1-A260 and view if the cell is empty or not. If it's not empty, copy it to next empty cell in column A at sheet "Summary". There is the code that I wrote.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

  Dim WS_Count As Integer
  Dim I As Integer
  Dim sheetName As String

  WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1

  For I = 1 To WS_Count
     sheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

 Dim rng As Range
 Dim row As Range
 Dim cell As Range

 Set rng = Range("A1:A260")

 For Each row In rng.Rows
   For Each cell In row.Cells
      If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
        cell.Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("A2").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

      End If

   Next cell
 Next row

Next I

End Sub
```

But every time that I run this code it seems to be infinity (or something near to infinity), because excel not responding. What do you suggest to change?
ps I'm very big noob @ vba programming, any explanations are welcome :)

Comment: the clipboard is a user tool, you should never use it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply iterate over the cells and use the `.value` property

```
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  r = 0
  For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not WS.Name = "Summary" Then
     For I = 1 To 260
       v = WS.Range("A" & I).Value
       If Not v = vbNullString Then
         r = r + 1
         Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & r) = v
       End If
     Next I
    End If
  Next WS
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do such tasks is to load all the data into arrays and operate on arrays instead of Excel cells.

Here is the code for your task that uses arrays (I added some comments, so you should know what is going on):

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim row As Long
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim nonEmptyCells() As Variant
    Dim firstEmptyRow As Long
    Dim destinationRange As Excel.Range
    '------------------------------------------------------------


    Set wkb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook


    'Iterate through all the worksheets, search through theirs first column
    'and collect data from all non-empty cells into a separate String array
    'nonEmptyCells().
    For Each wks In wkb.Worksheets

        If wks.Name <> "Summary" Then

            With wks

                Debug.Print wks.Name

                'Read data into array and use this array to operate on those
                'data later instead of operating directly on Excel cells -
                'it will improve performance.
                data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(260, 1))


                'Iterate through all the values read from the currently
                'processed worksheet.
                For row = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)

                    'Assign value from array to variable for better readability.
                    cellValue = data(row, 1)

                    'If this value is not empty, add it to array nonEmptyCells.
                    If cellValue <> vbNullString Then
                        Call addEntry(nonEmptyCells, cellValue)
                    End If

                Next row


            End With

        End If

    Next wks



    'At this point all the values from non-empty cells from all worksheets
    'are collected in array nonEmptyCells. All we have to do is to paste
    'them to worksheet "Summary"


    'Check if there are any values in nonEmptyCells. If not, there is nothing
    'to be printed out in "Summary" worksheet and we can leave the macro.
    If countDimensions(nonEmptyCells) = 0 Then Exit Sub



    'Find first empty row in worksheet "Summary".
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("Summary")
    firstEmptyRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1


    Set destinationRange = wks.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1).Resize(UBound(nonEmptyCells) - LBound(nonEmptyCells), 1)
    destinationRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(nonEmptyCells)



End Sub
```

Please note that in order to make this macro working properly you need to paste this function into your code: [function for adding new entry to dynamic array](http://mielk.pl/en/download/code/array/addEntry.txt).

Comment: That is great solution, thanks for it! Do you have an idea how to add and the sheet name in column B in my Summary ( Something similar to map (key is the sheet name)?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add the non-blank cells you will want to change the "= vbnullstring" to "<> vbnullstring" and you probably only want to check for non-null values if it is not the Summary sheet. I also noticed that you were always adding the new line to cell A2 in the Summary sheet, basically eliminating what you had previously added. This should fix all these issues while still keeping most of your original code in place.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rw as long

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1
    rw = 1

    For I = 1 To WS_Count
        sheetName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

        If sheetName <> "Summary" Then
            Set rng = Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1:A260")

            For Each row In rng.Rows
                For Each cell In row.Cells

                    If cell.Value <> vbNullString Then
                        cell.Copy

                        Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & rw).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                        rw = rw + 1

                    End If

                Next cell
            Next row

        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```